# PhongMaterial for InstancedBufferGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to create a scene with thousands of simple meshes, so I decided to use InstancedBufferGeometry. I copied most of my code from this example: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_instancing_dynamic

Instancing works, but only with the `THREE.RawShaderMaterial` from example:

```
instancedMaterial = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial( {
    uniforms: {
        map: { value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'textures/grassAlpha.png' ) },
        time: { value: 0 }
    },
    vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent
} );
```

And shaders:

```
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    precision highp float;
    uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
    uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
    uniform float time;
    attribute vec3 position;
    attribute vec3 offset;
    attribute vec2 uv;
    attribute vec4 orientation;
    varying vec2 vUv;
    void main() {
        vec3 vPosition = position;
        vec3 vcV = cross( orientation.xyz, vPosition );
        vPosition = vcV * ( 2.0 * orientation.w ) + ( cross( orientation.xyz, vcV ) * 2.0 + vPosition );
        vUv = uv;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( offset + vPosition, 1.0 );
    }
</script>

<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision highp float;
    uniform sampler2D map;
    varying vec2 vUv;
    void main() {
        vec4 texelColor = texture2D( map, vUv );
        if ( texelColor.a < 0.4 ) discard;
        gl_FragColor = texelColor;
    }
</script>
```

But how can I use `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial` instead of this simple shader? If I create mesh using other material, for example basic or phong, it just disappears (or maybe becomes fully transparent, but no errors in the console).

Comment: See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/14012.

Comment: @WestLangley nice example, thank you. DepthMaterial is needed only for casting, not receiving shadows, is it true? I already have a working shader from Mugen87's answer, but it don't receive shadows. Maybe you know what I should change in the fragmentShader code to make it work with receiving shadows properly.

Comment: Generally, a `CustomDepthMaterial` is needed when instancing to properly cast _and_ receive shadows. This is because an object can cast a shadow onto itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Material.onBeforeCompile](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/materials/Material.onBeforeCompile). The code looks like this with a single instanced attribute `offset`.

```
material.onBeforeCompile = function ( shader ) {
    shader.vertexShader = 'attribute vec3 offset;\n' + shader.vertexShader;
    shader.vertexShader = shader.vertexShader.replace( '#include <begin_vertex>',
       [
         'vec3 transformed = vec3( position + offset );',
       ].join( '\n' )
     );
     materialShader = shader;
};
```

**Demo**: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/erGbXj?editors=1010

Comment: It works, but how to make instanced meshes receive shadows? `receiveShadow` is set on `true`, light can cast shadows too.

Comment: It is necessary to apply more modifications to the shader. Keep an eye on the following thread. I guess there will be soon a new example that illustrates what you are looking for: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/13995

Comment: it took some time, but I found out why shadows don't work in your pen. This is how instanced geometry should be initialisated:
`var geometry = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry(); geometry.copy( new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 1, 1, 1 ) );`
There's no need to copy every attribute yourself.

Comment: @Mugen87 thanks for your answer. It helped me a lot. That PR nicely manipulated positions and shadows accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There exists an npm package that aims to solve this and provide a user friendly abstraction for this problem.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-instanced-mesh

[It seems to be working with shadows fine.](http://dusanbosnjak.com/test/webGL/three-instanced-mesh/webgl_instanced_mesh_v4.html)

*NOTE: This is a side-effect of making it just work with everything three has to offer, it's not specifically designed to render with shadows, but to render properly with depth effects, with all the materials and cameras etc.*

**`onBeforeCompile` may break certain things depending on how it's being used.** It seems to be more by design than a bug but just beware of it:

I think it's non deterministic - if you put `if else` in there, you might get a different shader compiled depending on the order of meshes in a scene.

`material.clone()` will not clone the entire object etc. The demo posted in the accepted answer is actually a good example of this behavior.
([see this issue on github](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/14009)).

Another issue may be that you find it hard to "chain" the logic that needs to happen. If you inherited a project where someone already uses `onBeforeCompile`

```
decorate_material_written_by_another_dev( material ){
  ...
  material.onBeforeCompile = shader => {} //oops, what if there is one in there already
  ...
}
```

None of this behavior is documented in the link the accepted answer refers to.

To reiterate, the question starts:

> I need to create a scene with thousands of simple meshes,

If you want to optimize thousands of simple meshes, you are referring to some kind of a scene graph

```
Scene
|-Mesh0000
|-Mesh0001
...
|-Mesh1000
```

Ideally, wouldn't you want a similar interface to `Mesh.position`, `Mesh.scale`, `Mesh.rotation`/`Mesh.quaternion`, no matter what the optimization ends up looking?

In other words, you shouldn't need to mess around much with strings, shaders, possibly not even materials.

Imagine if you could do this:

```
import { InstanceMesh, InstanceMaterial } from 'examples/instancing' //or npm module

const myInstanceMesh = new InstanceMesh(
  new CubeGeometry(), 
  new InstanceMaterial(new MeshStandardMaterial())
)

myInstanceMesh.material.onBeforeCompile = onBeforeCompile_unrelated_to_instancing
```

This fails if the person who implemented the example used `onBeforeCompile`. Which is why you don't see any examples like this.